# In Burp Suite how do I completely hide the file type to allow upload of .php files to unsecure sites?

Tags: file-type, penetration-testing, burp

Currently, I am trying to use burp suite to get around a websites file upload filtering system (specifically designed to practice pen-testing) to upload malicous .php code. At present whilst I have got round some filters, my php code is still being detecting by the filter and I'm not sure what else to change in my header?

[Header shown in Burp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2SeU.png)

[Web error after forwarded request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt5SD.png)

I am currently completing an online exercise that teaches how to exploit poorly coded web-applications, in this casing being a website with incorrect file upload filtering.

To perform the attack I am trying to upload some php code to the site via burp proxy. So far I have got round the first MIME type filter by changing the content type from application/x-php to image/gif. Now when I try to upload the file I get a new error (shown) which says incorrect magic number. As such I know I have hidden the php fully but I'm not sure what's giving it away?

In addition, one of the "supporting questions" to help one find the right answer is shown below:

"What file header did you use to bypass the file check (in hex)? (Submit answer as \xXX\xXX with no spaces)?"

Is this suggesting I have to encode part of the header in hex to avoid detection? What is the meaning of \xXX\xXX? Isn't hex usually as series of doublets?

Answer (score 0):

`xxx\xxx` are used as a placeholder, e.g. for `text/html`. And yes, encoding is usually employed to trick a **WAF** - but try somewhere else than at the content type in the header.